# HttpClient GetAsync returns 404 on local Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, dotnet-httpclient

I got two Visual Studio Instances, one with an ASP.NET .NET6 Application, and another one with a .NET Framework 4.8 console application, from which I want to call the web app.

Whenever I call the web application, I get a 404 response. When I copy the URL in the browser, it works.

The controller code of the web app looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Authorize]
public class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult GetStuff()
    {
        return Ok(42);
    }
}
```

Entering `https://localhost:7065/Api/GetStuff` in the browser returns `42`.

However, this simple console application fails:

```
internal class Program
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    static void Main() => new Program().RunAsync().Wait();

    private async Task RunAsync()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7065/Api/GetStuff");
    }
}
```

I am sure this is something obvious, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: If you remove attribute Authorize from your ApiController does it work when you send request through your app?

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you so much. Why does it return 404, and not 403 or 401, though?

Comment: Your app is attempting to negotiate an authentication scheme which is why you end up with the default HTTP Basic authentication. At final you are redirected and you got 404 instead of 401, but if you want be sure what happens when you send request you can install some HTTP request/response tracking tool (you have HTTP toolkit application to monitor request/response).